# MongoDB Query - is this possible?

Tags: php, mongodb

Is this possible to make a query like that in MongoDB?

```
SELECT  `pro` , COUNT( * ) , SUM( `age` ) 
FROM  `k_pin` 
GROUP BY  `pro
```

If yes, how? PHP example would be perfect.

Comment: It is called NoSQL for a reason :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mongoDB call would be as follows:

```
db.k_pin.aggregate([ 
 { $group: {_id:"$pro", count:{$sum:1}, sum_age:{$sum:"$age"}} }
])
```

Which can all be found here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Aggregation+Framework+Mapping+Chart

I will leave the php up to you, since that is the easy part.

Comment: Note that this will only work with MongoDB 2.1+, as the aggregation framework has not yet been released in a stable version.

Comment: Yes that is true.  I was giving the easiest example for him(since he didnt give a version) map/reduce would be the other option which is also clearly documented on the mongodb website from the link I provided.